# Tried to store a image into sqlite and when I try to retrieve it it's one byte instead of 2 million bytes

Tags: ios, sqlite, uiimage, blob, nsdata

When I try to store an image into sqlite, I have converted that image into NSData and there are more than 2,000,000 bytes in the imageData.

When I try to retrieve it from the sqlite database, it became ONE byte.

Here's my code:

Insert image into sqlite:

```
    -(void)INSERTCLAIMATTACHMENT:(NSString *)tablename
                    PARENTID:(long long)parentid
           ATTACHMENTCONTENT:(UIImage *)attachmentimage
              ATTACHMENTNAME:(NSString *)attachmentname
{
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    const char *dbPath = [_databasePath UTF8String];

    Global * g = [[Global alloc]init];
    NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc]init];
    imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(attachmentimage);

    if(sqlite3_open(dbPath, &_DB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO CLAIM_ATTACHMENT_ITEM ('PARENT_ID', 'CLAIM_ATTACHMENT_CONTENT', 'CLAIM_ATTACHMENT_NAME', 'CLAIM_ATTACHMENT_SIZE') VALUES ('%lld', '?', '%@', '%lu')", parentid,attachmentname, [imageData length]];
        const char *insert_statement = [insertSQL UTF8String];

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(_DB,insert_statement, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
           {
               sqlite3_bind_blob(statement, 2, [imageData bytes], [imageData length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
               if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
               {
                   [g showCustomAlertView:@"Successfull" message:@"Attachment has been added into database."];
               }
               else{
                   [g showCustomAlertView:@"Failure" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", sqlite3_errmsg(_DB)]];
               }

           }
        else{
            [g showCustomAlertView:@"Failure" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", sqlite3_errmsg(_DB)]];
        }

    }
    else{
        [g showCustomAlertView:@"Failure" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", sqlite3_errmsg(_DB)]];
    }
    sqlite3_close(_DB);
}
```

Retrieve image from sqlite

```
-(NSMutableArray *)SELECTATTACHMENTFROMCLAIMATTACHMENTITEM:(long long)rowID
{
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    const char *dbPath = [_databasePath UTF8String];

    Global * g = [[Global alloc]init];

    NSMutableArray *attachmentArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    if(sqlite3_open(dbPath, &_DB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM CLAIM_ATTACHMENT_ITEM WHERE PARENT_ID = '%lld'", rowID];
        const char *query_Statement = [querySQL UTF8String];

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(_DB, query_Statement, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                AttachmentItem * attachment = [[AttachmentItem alloc]init];
                NSData *attachmentImageData = [[NSData alloc]initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 2) length:sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, 2)];

                UIImage *attachmentImage = [UIImage imageWithData:attachmentImageData];

                NSString *attachmentName = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];
                attachment.attachmentImage = attachmentImage;
                attachment.attachmentName = attachmentName;
                [attachmentArray addObject:attachment];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            [g showCustomAlertView:@"Failure" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", sqlite3_errmsg(_DB)]];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        [g showCustomAlertView:@"Failure" message:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%s",sqlite3_errmsg(_DB)]];
    }


    sqlite3_close(_DB);

    return attachmentArray;

}
```

What happen? Why the image data shrinked into one single byte for me :(
I'm guessing that the blob cannot store that size of data maybe?

Comment: FYI - It's probably a bad idea to store images in the database. You should write them to the file system and just store the filename in the database. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346879/store-images-in-sqlite-or-just-a-reference-to-it

Comment: One other thing. Avoid `SELECT * FROM ...` usage. Explicitly list out the column names instead of using `*`. It will make your code much easier to read and it avoid strange bugs if you later modify the schema and the column order isn't what you expected.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to `sqlite_bind_blob` is passing the wrong field index. You only have one `?` in the `INSERT` statement so the index should be `1`, not `2`.

```
sqlite3_bind_blob(statement, 1, [imageData bytes], [imageData length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

Additionally, you need to remove the quotes from the `?` in the `INSERT` statement:

```
NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO CLAIM_ATTACHMENT_ITEM ('PARENT_ID', 'CLAIM_ATTACHMENT_CONTENT', 'CLAIM_ATTACHMENT_NAME', 'CLAIM_ATTACHMENT_SIZE') VALUES ('%lld', ?, '%@', '%lu')", parentid,attachmentname, [imageData length]];
```

The main reason to use a `?` combined with the appropriate `sqlite3_bind_xxx` statement instead of building a query using `stringWithFormat:` is that values are properly quoted and escaped for you.

Comment: I see... so the parameter detects the index of '?' instead of string format specifier?

Comment: The `sqlite3_bind_xxx` functions know nothing of Objective-C and certainly nothing of `NSString` format specifiers.

Comment: Alright sir you deserve my upvote and acception, thank you

Comment: I've tried to fix that but after that it still 1 byte instead of original 2m bytes

Answer (score 1):

```
VALUES ('%lld', '?', '%@', '%lu')
```

The `%` replacements are textual, but `?` is handled by the SQL engine and works only when the parameter marker appears where it is an expression.

With the quotes, `'?'` is just a string containing the single character `?`.

You have to write the parameter without quotes:

```c
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT ... VALUES ('%lld', ?, '%@', '%lu')", ...];
```

And this statement has only a single SQL parameter, so its index must be 1, not 2.

Comment: Oh my god that's exactly what I was wrong. Thank you so much!